# Avoid compilation ISO C++

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors

By default, on Ubuntu, when I try to compile with g ++ like:

```
g++ -o name file.cpp
```

Sometimes it responds with "ISO C++ forbids..."

If I don't want to compile with ISO, what flag should I use?

Comment: You probably used Variable Length Arrays. They're not actually part of C++ (just C99 and later). So, you want proprietary extensions. Keep in mind, your code won't be portable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just stick to the language rules, and write legal C++ code?

Comment: @jalf Not if he inherited Cx9 code or code using proprietary extensions

Comment: Thank to you all very much...now it's clearer

Comment: @sehe true, but if he did, he would normally also have inherited a build system which invokes the compilers with the necessary flags. :)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
g++ -std=c++0x
```

or

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x
```

Note: If you proprietary enable extensions, your code will become less portable.

> C++11 features are available as part of the "mainline" GCC compiler in the trunk of GCC's Subversion repository and in GCC 4.3 and later. To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x to your g++ command line. GCC 4.7 and later support -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 as well.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use gcc/g++ extensions, then use `-std=gnu++0x`. Assuming of course it's not a case of "you can't actually do this in C++".